# "It is no restriction to assume, w/o loss of generality, that"

Tags: proof-explanation, central-limit-theorem

In this proof for CLT, the author said "it is no restriction to assume that $\mu=0, \sigma=1$". This is not clear to me. Can anyone share your thoughts?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>


<kbd>[image]</kbd>

### My attempt

Note that
\begin{align}
    \varphi_{\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}}(t)
    &=
    E (
    e^{it \frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}}
    ) \\
    &=
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
    e^{it \frac{s_n-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}} 
    \cdot
    f_{S_n}(s_n)
    ~ds_n,
\end{align}
and,
\begin{align}
    \varphi_{\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}}(t)
    &=
    E (
    e^{it \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}}
    ) \\
    &=
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
    e^{it \frac{s_n}{\sqrt{n}}} 
    \cdot
    f_{S_n}(s_n)
    ~ds_n.
\end{align}

These two are NOT equal.

### My thoughts

I think the equality in blue circle does not hold quantitatively in general. It holds based on some explanation and understanding.

Comment: Suppose CLT holds for all centered variates with unit variance. Can you show it holds for general variates? (In fact, there really is nothing to show…it’s almost tautological!) Also, the equality you say does not hold in general holds here because unit variance and centered was assumed. Obviously it won’t hold without those assumptions. The Fourier transform, for example of a non centered variate necessarily has imaginary part

Answer (score 1):

Following Andrew's comment, I will give a proof or explanation.

### Proof

We want to know the distribution of
\begin{align}
    \frac{(\sum_i X_i) -n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}.
\end{align}

However,
\begin{align}
    \frac{(\sum_i X_i) -n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}
    =
    \frac{\sum_i \frac{X_i - \mu}{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}
    =
    \frac{\sum_i Y_i}{\sqrt{n}},
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
    E(Y_i) &= 0 \\
    Var(Y_i) &= 1.
\end{align}

That is, the LHS and RHS of Eq (1) have the same distribution. That is why we can just focus on $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ instead.